# Sheets Formula Help: Combine all matching values together (A,B,C, not A+B+C), if column title matches

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

(Google Sheets, Formula/equation help, running on Windows 10, comparing 2 sheets within one google sheet doc)

Hello,

I need to mass add cell values together IF they match column A value. I need when the column A value is matched, column H all matching values need to populate into one cell on another sheet. I am not sure what equation to use to do this as column H is numbers and cannot use Sumifs.

Second time poster, so have to attach link to google sheets screenshot.

[image: 1]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I cannot, there is confidential pricing in the reded out sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!H2:H}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "select Col1 offset 1", 0), SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!H2:H}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", 0)="",,QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!H2:H&","}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "limit 0", 1))),,9^9))), "\s|,$", ), ",", ","&CHAR(10))})
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TtTW7iDZiQ_9FVA6VqeN6-uVJW9WgwLr7vETZed7jZU/edit#gid=1262139620)